# Cant send message in aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

I have an id from a group chat, but when I try to send a message there, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\bot5.py", line 77, in cmd_create_dem
    await bot.send_poll(chat_id=id,
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 1532, in send_poll
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_POLL, payload)
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 231, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "D:\github\repositories\python-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.ChatNotFound: Chat not found
```

If I try to send to any other group, then everything works. Why is that?

code:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['opros'])
async def prikol(message: types.Message):
    id = {-numbers}
    await bot.send_message(id, 'ok')
```

i changed my id to {numbers}

My id has 14 characters including the minus, while the rest of the groups have like 10 characters. Could this affect something?

Comment: Show please a bit of code

Comment: I have added the code to the question

Comment: why do you use minus? maybe it doesn't have char with minus.

Comment: Explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you get id without -100 (example: 1234561) you need add "-100" to this id to use it with bot (ex: -1001234561)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**I have two suggestions:**

1. Be sure that your bot must be an admin of this group to be able to send messages.
2. Double check group id.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33010012)